# in .NET, is the class object passed by value or by reference

Tags: .net

We know that integers are passed as value types unless we use ref keyword.

But what about class objects?

Will updates within functions cause update to the object?

What about string? It is a reference type. Is the behaviour same in this case when passing string to function?

Comment: By reference, you can find this information in every .NET tutorial, in the MSDN documentation, and you check it yourself with few lines of code.

Comment: This is a ridiculous question and could be answered in a few seconds with a Google search. It flagging allowed for questions which show no attempt at research

Comment: Since you cannot *update* a `string`, surely the point is moot about how strings are passed to a function?

Comment: string is also reference type.  Then why doesnt its value too get updated within a function and available outside

Comment: @variable It's an exceptional case: strings are immutable. RTFM! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Immutability

Comment: Do you mean classes are mutable .?

Comment: I mean: RTFM. Sorry for being harsh, you ask about basics that are available all over the internet. Please stop being lazy, and use your reading skills. If you'll have some more specific questions regarding particular issues afterwards, I'm sure you're welcome to ask a better question.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the behaviour of we pass an attribute of object like a.id to function and update the attribute.  Then will the value persist outside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

objects aren't passed as parameters - *references* are. The *reference* is passed by value, but of course the *object* that the reference refers to is still the same *object*.

[Passing Reference-Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> A variable of a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) **does not** contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) or [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keyword.

(**my emphasis**)

---

And from the [C# language specification, version 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 4:

> Value types differ from reference types in that variables of the value types directly contain their data, whereas variables of the reference types store ***references*** to their data, the latter being known as ***objects***. With reference types, it is possible for two variables to reference the same object, and thus possible for operations on one variable to affect the object referenced by the other variable. With value types, the variables each have their own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one to affect the other.

Which is why I draw the distinction that objects aren't passed at all - because you never have a variable *containing* an object.

Comment: And that's commonly referred to as "passing object by reference".

Comment: @BartoszKP - but since the C# language also has a `ref` keyword which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) as causing an argument to be passed by reference, and since that's *not* the same as when you pass the reference by value, it's a distinction worth drawing.

Comment: But saying that "objects aren't passed as parameters" is misleading, because they are. And it is called as I've mentioned above.

Comment: No, objects are not passed.  References are passed, and they're passed by value.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels I'm not saying how it works. I'm saying how it is referred to (must I repeat this again?). Saying that an object is "passed" is common.

Comment: Yes, but saying that this is "pass by reference" just leads to two confused follow up questions - if this is "pass by reference", then surely `ref` is nonsense? And also, how do I pass my object by value?

Comment: I'm not saying that you're wrong. I'm saying that you're explaining it in a misleading way. `ref` is in fact very rarely used for reference types (not to say never) - only in some very specific scenarios, which should be probably refactored anyway.

Comment: BartoszKP, you're wrong.  The references to the instances are passed by value, even though the types that those references point to, are reference types.

Comment: @BartoszKP - added section from more documentation. Without `ref`, the documentation refers to this, still, as a form of pass by value.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels You seem to no understand my comments. I'm not saying that "references to the instances" are not "passed by value". I'm referring to a common phrase, that although being inaccurate (as you obsessively repeat), is convenient to use and in fact **is** commonly used for simplicity.

Comment: I don't know of anyone that commonly uses this phrase for this situation because, as we can plainly see evidence of, it leads to confusion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe downvote was too much for such a subtlety. I still don't like your explanation, but don't have the time to search for sources where the phrase I'm referring to is conveniently used.

Comment: @BartoszKP - added a quote from the C# language specification where it draws the distinction between references and objects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You don't get my point. I'll try to rephrase - I'm not saying that your statements are wrong. I'm saying that starting your answer with "objects aren't passed as parameters" *could possibly be* misleading to a beginner reading your answer. Just that, nothing more.

Comment: I think that spreading inaccurate information for the sake of simplicity increases confusion and complexity. :)

Comment: @BartoszKP - and I'm indicating that, *if* a beginner thinks that objects are being passed at all, the most useful thing you can do is to *dispel* that belief. Not humour them and let them continue to have an inaccurate model.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Not sure how you've deduced that I want to spread inaccurate information. Explaining what is and should be *exactly* understood by the phrase I'm referring to is of course essential, especially in the context of such question (leaving aside why answer such a question when it should be closed instead...). Repeating for the N-th time: I'm not arguing about the point/the essence of this answer, just about its form.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ^ Also, some examples of commonness of this phrase: "any object can be passed to this overload" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxa9y69d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx etc.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the behaviour of we pass an attribute of object like a.id to function and update the attribute. Then will the value persist outside the function?

Comment: .NET has a concept called Attributes, but I suspect what you're actually asking about are Properties (or possibly Fields). It's no different really than if you have the same value in a local variable. A *copy* of either the value type or of the *reference* is passed to the function. It can freely modify its copy but this has no effect on the original. And if it *is* a reference that is passed, then both the original and the copy continue to *reference* the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the instance is passed by value.  However, since a class is a reference type, the changes you make to the instance, are also reflected outside the method where you've made those changes.

However, when you overwrite the reference inside the method, that will not be reflected outside the method, unless you specify that the object reference should be passed by ref.

In other words: you do not pass an object as a parameter to a function.  You're passing a reference to an object as a parameter to a function.  That reference is passed by value, unless you specify otherwise via the ref keyword.

Strings are reference types, but they act as value types.  This means that you cannot 'change' an existing string.  When you want to modify a string, for instance by adding another string to it:

```
string s = "hello";
s = s + ", world!";
```

In fact, you are not 'changing' a string, but actually creating a new string instance.  In my example above, s + ", world!" appends 2 strings but the result is a new string instance.
This means that after the execution of line 2, `s` will point to another object instance.

Comment: Passed by value.  you can overwrite the reference inside the method, but outside the method, the reference will point to the original string again.

Comment: But why? Isnt string also a reference type like a class object

Comment: String is a reference type.  However, when you pass the string to the method, the reference to that string is passed.   When you change the string variable, you actually create a new string instance, and the reference that you've passed is actually pointing to the new instance.  However, since the string reference is passed by value, the change to the reference itself is not 'persisted' once you leave the method.  At that moment, your string reference is pointing to the original string again.

Comment: What other exceptions are there like this? I mean besides class , which other things get passed as reference?

Comment: Nothing is passed by reference unless you specify it via 'ref'.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the behaviour of we pass an attribute of object like a.id to function and update the attribute. Then will the value persist outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all parameters are passed by value in C#. Parameters are only passed by reference if you explicitly include an out or ref modifier. However, you need to be aware that when the type of the parameter is a reference type, you're passing a reference rather than an actual object.

Comment: What about string, even string is a ref type but it is passed as value !